I am having issue while running my app with gradle error
A build operation failed.

Could not move temporary workspace
(C:\Users\Zoheth.gradle\caches\8.9\transforms\5f81bb56960adfcb8e3b54c856d0094a-67a45c2c-1ad3-461d-bc8e-a8a2444ed409)
to immutable location
(C:\Users\Zoheth.gradle\caches\8.9\transforms\5f81bb56960adfcb8e3b54c856d0094a)
Could not move temporary workspace
(C:\Users\Zoheth.gradle\caches\8.9\transforms\5f81bb56960adfcb8e3b54c856d0094a-67a45c2c-1ad3-461d-bc8e-a8a2444ed409)
to immutable location
(C:\Users\Zoheth.gradle\caches\8.9\transforms\5f81bb56960adfcb8e3b54c856d0094a)
Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with
--info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights. Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

Can anyone help me with this error?

Run gradle clean to clean the Gradle cache directory. and try again

I did brother but its not resolving my issue.

Which versions of Flutter and Gradle (and the Android Gradle Plugin) are you using? Are they compatible? It might also help to open the android subfolder as a project in Android Studio, it might highlight some potential issues in Android/Gradle configuration files.

Please post the results of flutter doctor

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.4894], locale en-US)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[X] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps
[√] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
[√] VS Code (version 1.93.1)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] Network resources
! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
@ChillBroDev
